# Laravel Polymorphic OneToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

Let's say I have model `House` and House is built of different Elements like bricks, windows, doors, etc.

Now I imagine having a method on my House model `elmentable()` and when I call `$house->elementable()->toArray()` I get an array of different elements like bricks, windows.. with their respective properties or keys in the case of an array.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to achieve this and if it is or if it is possible.

Any help on how to implement the mentioned use case would be great.

Comment: be more specific, like are the elemnts gonna be models or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need a polymorphic relationship that has subclassed models. Say `Brick` and `Window` models which inherit from a `Supply` model.

```
class House extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'houses'

    public function supplies()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Supply::class, 'house', 'supply_type', 'supply_id');
    }

    public function bricks()
    {
        return $this->supplies()->where('type', 'brick');
    }

    public function windows()
    {
        return $this->supplies()->where('type', 'window');
    }

    public function doors()
    {
        return $this->supplies()->where('type', 'door');
    }

}


class Supply extends Model {
    protected $table = 'supplies';

    public function house()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('house');
    }
}

class Brick extends Supply {}
class Window extends Supply {}
class Door extends Supply {}
```

This approach would give you the collective list of supplies as well as the benefit of separating the supply types nicely.

Not a typical polymorphic relationship but I think should work.

Comment: This looks good, I will try it out and let you know. Thank you very much. I asked this question a few times but it didn't seem that people understood my question. This looks like something I am searching for even though, as you said, it's not the typical polymorphic relationship. I guess it's a Laravel polymorphic relationship :)

Comment: but in this approach i would still have only one table for all my supplies? so most of the properties would be nullable? is there a way to make brick, window.. have their own tables?

Comment: Sure there's no reason they can't have individual tables. Within each model you can set the `protected $table = 'bricks' // windows, doors, etc.`, for example.